# WCF service for Java client

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, soap

Creating service on .NET for Java client. Messages will be signed by certificate and will work over https.
Java client will be provide signature in form of **Issuer Name and Serial**. Are WCF support this ?
If yes, which binding use ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be supported by WCF which will be hosted in IIS. This would mean that your WCF service would be hosted in IIS with HTTPS or the binding would be configured with the certificate coming from same CA as the client certificate.

Comment: Problem is on message level, not transaport.